# Vexing linq to sql predicate building in a for loop

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm building a LINQ query using a loop that appends predicates using an array:

```
foreach (string tag in tags)
{
    result = result.Where(p => (p.TagsDelimited).Contains("," + tag + ","));
}
```

This creates all the necessary clauses, but each clause compares only the last element in the tags array, producing the sql

```
(((',' + [t0].[TagsDelimited]) + ',') LIKE '%,taglast,%') AND (((',' + [t0].[TagsDelimited]) + ',') LIKE '%,taglast,%')
```

instead of one clause for each tag.

I can work around this by adding

```
string temp = tag;
```

inside the for loop and using temp instead of tag.

**The question is: How is this possible!?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda captures the variable, not the value.

For more explanation, you might want to read my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658818/linqtosql-strange-behaviour/658840#658840)