# C# Predicate builder with using AND with OR

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

I have the following class:

```
public class testClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

and the following code:

```
            var list = new List<testClass>();
            list.Add(new testClass { name = "name", id = 1, age = 30 });
            list.Add(new testClass { name = "name", id = 2, age = 22 });
            list.Add(new testClass { name = "name", id = 3, age = 20 });
            list.Add(new testClass { name = "name", id = 4, age = 30 });
            list.Add(new testClass { name = "name", id = 5, age = 27 });
            list.Add(new testClass { name = "name", id = 6, age = 30 });

            var qble = list.AsQueryable();

            var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<testClass>();
            pred.Or(x => x.name == "name" && x.id == 1);
            pred.Or(x => x.age == 30);
            var predQuery = qble.AsExpandable().Where(pred);
```

My aim is to create a query that returns all records where:

```
id = 1 and name = "name"
```

OR

```
age = 30
```

So for the query above, it should return the items at index 0, 1, 5

For the above query it does as I want.

However, I now want to the build the predicate by combining a set of queries, rather than explicitly defining them. So I now have the following 2 queries:

```
var query1 = list.Where(x => x.name == "name" && x.id == 1);
var query2 = list.Where(x => x.age == 30);
```

and I want to build the query based on the variables `query1` and `query2`, without explicitly defining the conditions - as these conditions will be dynamically defined and I do not know what they are,and they will be defined in different places.

My guess is I need to do something like this (continuing from above):

```
var qble = list.AsQueryable();

var query1 = list.Where(x => x.name == "name" && x.id == 1);
var query2 = list.Where(x => x.age == 30);

var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<testClass>();
pred.Or(query1);
pred.Or(query2);
var predQuery = qble.AsExpandable().Where(pred);
```

but this is not quite correct as the predicate builder will not accept the query as a parameter.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is there a need to separate the queries?

Comment: @jonathan.ihm I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are actually trying to solve/build? What is the "big picture"?

Comment: @Alex I mean Can't you just do x.name == "name" && x.id == 1 || x.age == 30

Comment: @Igor I am trying to create an dynamic OR clause

Comment: @jonathan.ihm no because the and clause is being built up in one place and then I need to check against a further condition and combine the results

Comment: Is someting like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782339/how-to-dynamically-add-or-operator-to-where-clause-in-linq?rq=1

Comment: @Igor it does not have to be predicates. I one place I am building up an AND clause, and then further down the line I need to check if either the AND clause is true, or if a further conditions is true

Comment: What do you mean by "Dynamic"? Is this a function and consumer of function will provide two filter expressions?

Comment: @sallushan By dynamic I mean the where clause is built up using a function depending on what parameters are passed into the query, and then added to the query

Comment: @Alex Is there any reason you can't use `Union`?

Comment: @yinnonsanders the query could be very big and I do not want it to run twice, I want to build it up and then run it once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create two `Predicate<T>` and invoke them in your `.Where` call at the end.

```
var qble = list.AsQueryable();

var query1 = new Predicate<testClass>(x => x.name == "name" && x.id == 1);
var query2 = new Predicate<testClass>(x => x.age == 30);

var predQuery = qble.AsExpandable().Where(x => query1(x) || query2(x));
```

Or you could build another `Predicate<T>` beforehand and use this

```
var query = new Predicate<testClass>(x => query1(x) || query2(x));
var predQuery = qble.AsExpandable().Where(query);
```