# IQueryable Where Extension Method with Or's

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

#### Duplicate:

> [How to dynamically add OR operator to WHERE clause in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782339/how-to-dynamically-add-or-operator-to-where-clause-in-linq)

I want to loop through a array of string values and build a linq expression

Where each item in the list is OR'ed together.

```
string[] search = new string[]{"A", "B", "C"};
foreach (string item in filterValues)
{
    searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(item));
}
```

The code above searched for "A" **AND** "B" **AND** "C"

I want to search for "A" **OR** "B" **OR** "C".

I know how to do this with Linq but I want to accomplish the same thing using extension methods.

Comment: why don't you post the linq sintax?

Comment: Your code won't work for the AND case. See the answer to the linked question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658818/linqtosql-strange-behaviour/658840#658840 for the reason it doesn't. You are basically capturing the same variable in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: It is a duplicate... I search stackoverflow looking for an answer... I guess my searching skills need improvements.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Try `searchQuery.Where(s => search.Contains(s));`.

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party but...

I recently created a blog around creating an IQueryable search extension method that enables the following syntax:

```
string[] search = new string[]{"A", "B", "C"};
var searchQuery = context.Users.Search(u => u.Name, search);
```

**Update : START**

I have since updated search extensions which has affected the way a search is performed to use a new fluent API. This means the above should now be written as

```
var searchQuery = context.Users.Search(u => u.Name)
                               .Containing("A", "B", "C");
```

More on the new api can be seen here: http://jnye.co/Posts/2030/searchextensions-search-strings-with-the-new-fluent-api

**Update : END**

http://jnye.co/Posts/8/generic-iqueryable-or-search-for-multiple-search-terms-using-expression-trees

https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions

I also have a nuget package that you can install from here:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/

However, if you want to do this yourself you will need to do the following:
Firstly you need to create the extension method

```
public static class QueryableExtensions  
{  
    public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> stringProperty, params string[] searchTerms)  
    {  
        if (!searchTerms.Any())  
        {  
            return source;  
        }  
  
        Expression orExpression = null;  
        foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)  
        {  
            //Create expression to represent x.[property].Contains(searchTerm)  
            var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);  
            var containsExpression = BuildContainsExpression(stringProperty, searchTermExpression);  
  
            orExpression = BuildOrExpression(orExpression, containsExpression);  
        }  
  
        var completeExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpression, stringProperty.Parameters);  
        return source.Where(completeExpression);  
    }  
  
    private static Expression BuildOrExpression(Expression existingExpression, Expression expressionToAdd)  
    {  
        if (existingExpression == null)  
        {  
            return expressionToAdd;  
        }  
  
        //Build 'OR' expression for each property  
        return Expression.OrElse(existingExpression, expressionToAdd);  
    }  
}
```

This can then be used as follows:

```
string[] search = new string[]{"A", "B", "C"};
var searchQuery = context.Users.Search(u => u.Name, search);
```

This will create the or query you are after.

Hope this answer is still relevant to you.

Comment: Thanks John Nye! What an elegant and full-featured solution. The NuGet package you have developed is fantastic!

Comment: Glad to have helped and that you are enjoying the nuget package. It's great to hear it is being well received

Answer (score 0):

```
var filterValues = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

var values =
    (from item in filterValues
     from value in searchQuery
     where value.Name.Contains(item)
     select value)
     .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this today. Then I finally realized that if I made the array into a List of Strings I could do a join. A queryextender control (.NET 4) is calling the function below. Dont forget the order by... its important. you'll get an error if you don't use it.

```
    Protected Sub FilterTestType(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CustomExpressionEventArgs)
    Dim _codes As List(Of String) = GetTestCodes()
    e.Query = From _tests In e.Query.Cast(Of LabTest)()
              Join _code In _codes On _tests.TestCode Equals _code
              Order By _tests.LoadDate Descending
              Select _tests
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution :

```
string[] search = new string[]{"A", "B", "C"};
foreach (string item in filterValues)
{
    searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(item)).Concat(searchQuery);
}
```

working good on my MVC3 WebApp

Comment: This will generate very inefficient SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

One approach for cases where you have a known number of where choices is simply gather the list of those you want to exclude, then apply the where method.

```
dim BASEQUERY = FROM blah in blahblahblah _
WHERE ....
select blah

For Each item In EXCLUDELIST
Dim sitem As String = item
BASEQUERY = BASEQUERY.Where(Function(py) py.YOURCOLUMN <> sitem)
Next
```

This will leave only those you want which is equivalent to a compound "or where" condition.  Note:  A high number of excluded items could be unreasonably slow.